# XCTest Element query count returning incorrect number of cells

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xctestcase, xcuitest

Using Xcode 9, Swift, XCUI Test

I am trying to test the number of results showing up in a table but when a second set/page of results is loaded into the table, the incorrect number/count of cells is returned.

There are 50 cells in the table per page.  When the last cell is loaded, the next set of 50 (or up to 50) is loaded, if there are more.

In my test case, we navigate to the page and the first 50 cells are loaded. When I call for .count of the cells, it is making the api call to return the 2nd page of results twice for some reason.  The 2nd page contains 20 results.  The end count should be 70 (50 for first page, 20 for second page), but the count is coming back as 90 because it is making the call for the 2nd page of results twice.

```
//This fails with 90 does not equal 70
let cells = app.tables["message_inbox_table"].cells
XCTAssertEqual(cells.count, 70)
```

It is calling `willDisplayCell` on the `tableViewController` for the last cell twice.

Why is the .count method making this happen twice therefore causing the cell count to be incorrect? And is there another approach to get the correct cell count in our UI tests?